# Desktop widget to show list of tasks

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, screenlets

In Unity Ubuntu 11.10 how I can have a screenlet with a list of tasks to do?

For example:

1- Update system.
2- Check mailbox.

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for both answers +1 to both for the effort ;)

I managed to bring a list of TODOs to the Ubuntu Desktop using [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php)

I just have to tweak it a little:

- Remove the Event and Calendar Windows
- Configure it to do a Custom Sorting

Answer (score 4):

The **[TODO Screenlet](http://sven-festersen.de/drupal/TODOScreenlet)** sounds like what you are looking for.

[image: Screenshot of the TODO Screenlet from the first linked page]

Additional information and a download link can be found on its [gnome-look.org page](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/LocalTODOScreenlet?content=114228). Alternatively, you can check out the source code for it at [GitHub](https://github.com/SvenFestersen/LocalTODOScreenlet).

If you need help on how to install additional Screenlets, check this section from the [Screenlets.org FAQ](http://screenlets.org/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_install_new_Screenlets.3F).

*Disclaimer: I have not actually used this software before.*

Comment: This screenlet is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you want this list to work but I have downloaded "screenlets" from the Ubuntu Software Centre and launched the screenlet "Lipik" which acts as like a small square note pad where I write my to do list.
Hope this helps.